# Modeling network as directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a network that could look like this:
[image: Network]
Basically, I want to know the minimum number of green circles that can disconnect the source and drain if removed/disabled. (in this case 1)
I have already succesfully implemented the Edmonds-Karp algrorithm, but I don't know how to model the network with directed edges, so I get the desired result.
If I just replace each connection between the nodes with two opposite directed edges with capacity 1, I get a max flow of 2 with EdmondsKarp, but I only need to remove 1 green circle to break the network.
How do I model my network as nodes and directed edged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce this problem to the standard s–t cut problem in directed graphs, which can then solved e.g. by the Edmonds–Karp algorithm. For each vertex v, create two vertices v_in
and v_out and a directed edge (v_in, v_out), and for each edge {v,w}, add two directed edges (v_out ,w_in) and (w_out , v_in). It is then not hard to see that a maximum flow from s_in to t_out corresponds to a minimum vertex cut between s and t.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly determined maximum flow - it is 2 for your network.

From definition of [flow network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network)

> A flow must satisfy the restriction
>   that the amount of flow into a node
>   equals the amount of flow out of it,
>   except when it is a source, which has
>   more outgoing flow, or sink, which has
>   more incoming flow

So for your middle node you have 2 as max flow (coming in and going out). So knowing only the max flow will not give you the answer for minimal cut.

The theorem

> max-flow min-cut theorem states that
>   in a flow network, the maximum amount
>   of flow passing from the source to the
>   sink is equal to the minimum capacity
>   which when removed in a specific way
>   from the network causes the situation
>   that no flow can pass from the source
>   to the sink

so, yes you know the amount of flow you need to remove, but you don't know in which way to remove it. I think this is not so trivial and that you will need to specifically look for min-cut.

Comment: After some fruit-less Googleing, I guess I'm going to try the "brute force" way first: Find max flow. Remove node with most flow through it. Repeat those 2 steps until max flow is zero. Number of removed nodes should be the minimum, so I just count that.

Comment: @Svante, no this would not give the correct answer - imagine a case where same max flow, value 7, goes through 2 set of nodes, frist through 4,2,1 and then through 3,2,2. Removing 4 and 3 would not bring it to zero and you would reach zero flow only after removing the last 2 in the second set. This way you would count too many nodes. But, I believe (did not go through the algorithm) that Edmonds-Karp examines the minimum cut scenario, but does not retain it. I would look for a way to modify the max flow algorithm in a way that would return the nodes through which max flow goes.

Comment: yeah just implemented it, and it didn't work. The max-flow and min-cut is always the same. But the min-cut is just the min sum of the flow on the edges to be cut to separate source and drain. So it doesn't really tell me more, or anything, about which edges or nodes are the critical ones.

Comment: @Svante, look for algorithm that actually returns all the min-cut edges (yes, really all if there are multiple solutions), then examine which set of edges has the least number of nodes.