# Code for Vertex-Disjoint Menger Problem in NON-planar graphs

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I am doing an EDA-analysis program. Reading some articles I have found that my problem has a name (Vertex-Disjoint Menger Problem). But all the articles describes algorithms for planar graphs - needless to say that I have non-planar undirected graphs.

This problem is equivalent to finding the minimum s-t vertex cut in a undirected graph.

Also, instead of high-level algorithmic descriptions, I would like functional C/C++ code. As far as I can tell, BOOST has no such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203529/modeling-network-as-directed-graph/4205147#4205147), finding the minimum s–t vertex cut in a undirected graph can be reduced to finding the minimum s–t edge cut in a directed graph, for which many algorithms and implementations exist.

Comment: Yes, by splitting each node into two, right? Yeah, that doesn't work. Consider splitting two nodes that have an edge and are the in the minimum s-t cut set. You will nessecarily have one edge too much.

Comment: I don't see why. Can you give a concrete example with the reduction mentioned in the other question?

Comment: I still don't see the problem. Cutting the two edges that correspond to the two central vertices would be an s–t edge cut. Could you maybe show what the result of the reduction would be in your opinion, and what the too large cut would be?